# Azure DevOps CI/CD and Separating Connection Strings from Source Control

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops

So I've been following many different idea/strategies through many blogs/SO posts but I haven't been able to find my idea solution.

### What I'm Using

- Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.6
- Git (source control)
- Azure DevOps CI/CD
- Azure App Service (to host the Web API)

### Goal

The goal is to use the Azure DevOps tools to commit my project changes, push (via Git) the changes to Azure DevOps repo, have the CI/CD build the projected follow the pipeline rules to deploying to dev/production/etc. All this while, keep connection strings out of source control.

Currently, I got a website (legacy Web Application) that has local connection string definitions on an external connection string file (based on this article [Connection Strings and Configuration Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files)). It's hosted as an App Service on Azure. Within my `.gitignore` file I made Git ignore the specific connection strings file so that it's not in source control. Using Azure's deployment from GitHub feature, the site gets updated with the source in GitHub. **However,** I had to manually upload the connection string file with false/bad data. I use Azure's application settings to define the connection strings themselves. This process works perfectly fine.

### The Problem

I have a new .Net Web API project started at .Net Framework 4.7.2. I also followed the article to separate the connection strings into a separate files so that I can also ignore the file in source control. When the Azure DevOps builds the project it fails saying:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2603,5):
>   Error : Copying file ConnectionStrings.config to
>   obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\ConnectionStrings.config failed. Could
>   not find file 'ConnectionStrings.config'.

Obviously, because I'm not adding this file to source control. Mainly because even during development I need to put actual connection string usernames/password.

### Question

What other solutions/features exist that can help accomplish this scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Don't put secrets in configuration files.

If all your resources reside in Azure, use Managed Service Identities so that you don't need to bother with connection strings.

If not, use [ARM templates and key vault-linked parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references) to manage your Azure infrastructure. Azure Web Apps allow you to override configuration files with app settings/connection strings *within the web app*. So simply use key vault to manage that stuff, and tell the web app to pull the values from key vault.

Comment: This "key vault" sounds interesting and something I was about to look into but wasn't sure yet. I'll be looking into it now.

Comment: After much review and trying to set this up, I'm stuck at about 75% implementing the key vault references. Mainly stuck on how to properly get the `connectionStrings` section on my `Web.config` file or figure out how to properly send the connection through to the `DbContext`. Though my question does not ask these details, this answer is the best answer as of now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

VSRM task to publish Web Apps supports overriding values in Web.config. You can keep your secrets in VSRM and replace them in the deployment time. See [File transforms and variable substitution reference # XML variable substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops#xml-variable-substitution)

Comment: Hi! Thanks. I was actually already using this, but I think you missed the part where I said *I need to put actual connection string usernames/password* on my local/debug files too and I don't want to commit these... or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @RoLYroLLs: don't to that, or put only *test* (or local) connection string usernames/password, not the real ones.

Comment: I don't want to, but even for development of this particular task I have to. which is why I don't want to commit the file and figure out a way to transform or reference something for it. Like how I think Key Vault works, but still trying to figure out how to get it to work. =)

Answer (score 2):

If you do need to put your actual connectionstring-file in your project for debug, and therefore add your path for connectionString in .gitignore, you could let Pipeline create a dummy connectionstring before the task VSBuild.
This can be done with the [File Creator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eliostruyf.build-task) who is available at [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/).
After that, you simply insert the actual connectionstring into the Configuration for the App Service in Azure.

Comment: Nice. Thanks got this.