# local.settings.json transformation during Azure CI/CD

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have been looking for a way to transform values in local.settings.json of azure functions during the release pipeline. Please note I am not publishing function directly from the visual studio as the release process is automated with azure CI/CD. I could find below link but it didn't mention anything to automate it as the part of CI/CD.

I know how can do the config transformation for appsettings.json in.net core but so far I know local.settings.json will not copy to the release folder and I don't want to create another .json file on top of local.settings.json

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs#function-app-settings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure DevOps CI/CD and Separating Connection Strings from Source Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54600972/azure-devops-ci-cd-and-separating-connection-strings-from-source-control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it in the Azure Release pipeline in the App Settings section as shown below. You can add all app settings key-value pairs using the syntax "-key value". For example, if you want to add an email address in the app settings of Azure function during release then write -Email "emailadress" under the App settings section of the release pipeline

[image]