# How to Change ConnectionStrings at Runtime for a Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, connection-string

I hope this is a simple question:

> How can you change 2 connection strings at runtime in the
>   `Global.asax` under `Application_Start()`

**Web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add connectionString="DB1" value=""/>
  <add connectionString="DB2" value=""/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

**Details**

Before I start getting questions as to why I'm doing this or reasons I shouldn't, please refer to the following post [Azure Key Vault Connection Strings and N-Layered Design](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54809790/286618).

Essentially, I'm trying to use Key Vault with an N-Layered application. The WebAPI defines the connection string via the `Web.config`. In order to avoid hard-coding connection strings, they will be stored in Key Vault. However, due to the `Unit Of Work` pattern used, I'm not sure the best route and I'm currently trying to figure out the potential solution of *injecting* or *changing* the connection string at runtime for the Web API project only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel maybe I have not understood the question (as I don't know anything about Azure Key Vault), but you are not really getting your connection string in `Application_Start`...

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43722030/how-to-get-connection-string-out-of-azure-keyvault/43732088#43732088), I think you can implement a function which would return the desired connection string based on a variable:

```
string GetConnectionString()
{
    if (/* some dynamic variable is set */) {
        return  "DB1";
    }
    else {
        return "DB2";
    }
}
```

Now, assuming you have the above function, you can use it to initialize your `DbContext`:

```
MyDbContext myDbContext = new MyDbContext(GetConnectionString());
```

Or if you are injecting your `DbContext`, you can use it in your DI code (ninject example):

```
kernel.Bind<IMyDbContext>()
    .ToConstructor(ctorArg => new MyDbContext(GetConnectionString()))
    .InRequestScope();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have seen this potential solution, but I'm not sure how to implement it with the N-Layered solution I provided on the linked post (which is why I created this separate post specifically for Web.Config and ConnectionStrings. Maybe you can take look at the other post and help answer that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54809790/286618

Comment: After a bit more research, I have found a few samples pointing to your ninject example to work with what I might be trying to do. I'm just not sure how to get it to work out just yet.