# How to change initial catalog at runtime when using a connection string and dapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string, dapper, ninject.web.mvc

I'm writing an MVC C# application.  I use dapper as a lightweight ORM.  My connection strings are defined with server and initial catalog, and currently if I need to access a different database I define another connection string, and use Ninject bindings to use a particular connection string based on the manager i'm injecting it into, like so:

```
public class NinjectBindings : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IDbConnection>().To<SqlConnection>()
           .WhenInjectedInto<DashboardManager>()
           .InRequestScope()
           .Named("myDashboard")
           .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbDashboard"].ConnectionString);

        Bind<IDbConnection>().To<SqlConnection>()
           .WhenInjectedInto<ScoreboardManager>()
           .InRequestScope()
           .Named("myScoreboard")
           .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbScoreboard"].ConnectionString);

    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work if I have code in the same Manager that needs to call stored procedures that are on different databases than the initially specified catalog.

Question is: Can I just define one connection string, lose all the ninject binding stuff above, and simply change the Initial Catalog to a point to a different database on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need both `Named` and `WhenInjectedInto` constraints for your bindings?

I believe you have a class that requires both `connectionstring`s, this could be achieved using `Named` binding:

```
Bind<IDbConnection>().To<SqlConnection>()
   .InRequestScope()
   .Named("myDashboard")
   .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbDashboard"].ConnectionString);

Bind<IDbConnection>().To<SqlConnection>()
   .InRequestScope()
   .Named("myScoreboard")
   .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbScoreboard"].ConnectionString);
```

And your class can get both connections:

```
public class ClassWith2DbDependency // <-- I would question this class for SRP violation
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _dashboardConnection;
    private readonly IDbConnection _scoreboardConnection;

    public ClassWith2DBDependency(
        [Named("myDashboard")] IDbConnection dashboardConnection
        [Named("myScoreboard")] IDbConnection scoreboardConnection)
    {
        _dashboardConnection = dashboardConnection;
        _scoreboardConnection = scoreboardConnection;
    }

    public void WriteTo2Dbs()
    {
        // execute dashboard DB procedure
        // execute scoreboard DB procedure
    }
}
```

---

> Can I just define one connection string, lose all the ninject binding
>   stuff above, and simply change the Initial Catalog to a point to a
>   different database on the fly?

Changing `Initial Catalog` doesn't affect an existing `SqlConnection`. It is possible to manage the dependencies yourself, but you still need 2 `connectionstring`s:

```
public class ClassWith2DbDependency
{
    public void WriteTo2Dbs()
    {
        var dashboardCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbDashboard"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dashboardCon))
        {
            // execute dashboard DB procedure
        }

        var scoreboardCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbScoreboard"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(scoreboardCon))
        {
            // execute scoreboard DB procedure
        }
    }
}
```

However, I do **NOT** recommend this approach, the above class **violates DI principle, by having [Opaque Dependencies](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/07/03/how-not-to-do-dependency-injection-in-nerddinner/)**.

---

I haven't seen your code, but it doesn't sound like you are using [Repository Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)? This could be a good option...

Comment: Thank you, I used your first solution.  Any ideas on how to make the named string generic so I can pass it in somehow before it is DI'd into the manager?  [Named("thisStringMightChangeOnTheFly")] IDbConnection dashboardConnection

Comment: You can implement something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54835484/how-to-change-connectionstrings-at-runtime-for-a-web-api/54836942#54836942), but keep in mind that changing a `connectionString` does not affect an existing connection.